# PHP proccessing array of many table data

Tags: php

Is there any way tou proccessing each table at PHP? For example I have this PHP code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" value="table1" name="tables[]" />Table 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" value="1000" name="var1[]" />1000</td>
<td><input type="hidden" value="2000" name="var2[]" />2000</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="table1" name="tables[]" />Table 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" value="1000" name="var1[]" />1000</td>
<td><input type="hidden" value="2000" name="var2[]" />2000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" value="3000" name="var1[]" />3000</td>
<td><input type="hidden" value="4000" name="var2[]" />4000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My input name has same name for each table (`tables, var1, and var2`). The problem if I use these method:

```
foreach ($_POST['var1'] as $cnt => $cat) {
   $table = $_POST['tables'][$cnt];
   $var2 = $_POST['var2'][$cnt];
   myFunction($table, $var2);
}
```

It will gave an error like "Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in bla bla bla"
Is there any idea how to create this code running for each table? FYI: my table is various, maybe 1,2,or 100. and for each table maybe have 1,2,3,or 100 rows, and each table may have different number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

U have this notice, because u want to get third element of `$_POST['tables']` array and this offset is not exist. Look at your html code, you have table array for first and second group. But in third group u dont have a tables array.

```
foreach ($_POST['var1'] as $cnt => $cat) {
    $var2 = $_POST['var2'][$cnt];    
    if (isset($_POST['tables'][$cnt])) {
        $table = $_POST['tables'][$cnt];
        myFunction($table, $var2); 
    }
}
```

Comment: OP did have 3 tables on his question at some stage, the person must of being editing through it very quickly and removed the `<td>` by accident.

Comment: sorry... i already edit my code... i have about 2 tables in my example.. but 1 have 1 row, the other have 2 row, giving example that my tables really various

Answer (score 0):

Currently looking at your code I can only see an issue with `$table` not being declared.

EDIT: From looking at the answer from Daredzik you edited your question and removed a `<td>` from your third table which is why you are getting offset errors. Look at your table and make sure it has all the correct data in it.

This is a working solution with output to show that it works:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {

    foreach ($_POST['tables'] as $index => $table) {

        $var2 = $_POST['var2'][$index];
        $var1 = $_POST['var1'][$index];

        echo 'table = ' . $table;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'var1 = ' . $var1;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'var2 = ' . $var2;
        echo '<br><br>';
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="table1" name="tables[]" />Table 1</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="1000" name="var1[]" />1000</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="2000" name="var2[]" />2000</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="table2" name="tables[]" />Table 2</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="1000" name="var1[]" />1000</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="2000" name="var2[]" />2000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="table3" name="tables[]" />Table 3</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="3000" name="var1[]" />3000</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="4000" name="var2[]" />4000</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button>Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: hello.. it is,,, just I said at my question, my tables really various. For example my first table have 1 row, second table has 2 rows..

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, there can be many rows and columns. I would create a two-dimensional array from your POST data:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="table1" name="tables[0][0]" />Table 1</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="1000" name="tables[0][1]" />1000</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="2000" name="tables[0][2]" />2000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="table1" name="tables[1][0]" />Table 2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="1000" name="tables[1][1]" />1000</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="2000" name="tables[1][2]" />2000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="3000" name="tables[2][1]" />3000</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="4000" name="tables[2][2]" />4000</td>
  </tr>
```

And then:

```
<?php
  $tables = $_POST['tables'];
  foreach($tables as $table){
    if(isset($table[0]) && isset($table[2])) myFunction($table[0], $table[2]);
  }
?>
```

`$tables[$x]` contains single row. And then `$tables[$x][0]` is the first `<input>`, and so on.

Comment: hello, so i just need 1 name with multi dimension array? then how to add that index auto incrementaly by looking for the main table (each parent)

Comment: Do you generate that table in a script or it is hardcoded?

Comment: You should use some variable (for examle in loop that generates table) to generate next index in array. If it was simply `tables[$i][]`, there will be a problem with undefined index `2` in array.

Comment: You can also add some code to process rows like the third row in your example code (where exists only two `input` fields).

Comment: back to my first question, so it's enough to use only 1 variable for each table?

Comment: Yes. But you have to specify at least first dimension index (you can't write `name="table[][]"`)

Comment: no prob... I'm gonna try that... thank you very much! will update this topic later...